# Optimizing a 3 layer asp.net mvc 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization, shared-hosting

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 5.0 web application. I am experiencing some issues from shared hosting server. They say, worker process is limited to 150MB and my application is taking beyond. So, firstly I wanted to work with garbage collection to reduce the load.

In my DAL I have inherited IDisposable to a class where I have customized methods and made a call to destructor at the end of it.

```
public class DbAccessSupport : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //cmd.Dispose();

        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                    // Manual release of managed resources.
            }

            // Release unmanaged resources.
                disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~DbAccessSupport() 
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}


public class MasterWithADO
{
    public int DALPostChatMsg(string xml)
    {
        using (DbAccessSupport DbAccessSupportForSP = new DbAccessSupport(true))
        {
            DbAccessSupportForSP.CommandText = "sp_PostSingleChatMsg";
            DbAccessSupportForSP.AddParameter("@inputXml", xml);

            return DbAccessSupportForSP.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to implement collection and compaction for 3 -tier architecture. If yes then I would have to implement this in BAL and Application Layer also, that is going to add processing overhead quite high.

Comment: Are you using entity framework? 150MB is way too low though. Try removing unused references from your code.

Comment: @ViVi, No, I am not using entity framework at any place but their reference is added in the project. I am also not using session but short lived session at very exceptional cases.